# Determine the Galois group of the polynomial $(x^3-2)(x^3-3)(x^2-2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt {-3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Determine the Galois group of the polynomial $(x^3-2)(x^3-3)(x^2-2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt {-3})$.

I tried to decompose the splitting field into a tower, but then it is very complicated in each step and since the degree is large, I cannot determine the group by guessing. It seems to me that Kummer theory might work, but there are $2$-degree and $3$-degree factors.

Comment: The polynomial isn't separable, though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake

Comment: @QuinnGreicius the characteristic is zero. Separability isn't an issue.

Comment: Ah, I see the typo correction. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that none of the polynomials above split up any further in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: Let $p(x)=p_{1}(x)p_{2}(x)p_{3}(x)$ be the above polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. An automorphism must permute the roots. Moreover, a root of $p_{i}$ can't be mapped to a root of $p_{j}$ for $i \neq j$. So it seems all you can do is permute the roots of the respective irreducible factors. Without having actually calculated it I would conjecture that the Galois group of the splitting field is $G=S_{3}\times S_{3}\times S_{2}$. You would have to check that each permutation actually does give an automorphism

Comment: I think yes,since each factor is of degree 2 or 3 and it is enough to show that they do not have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$(√-3)

Comment: But it is still unclear whether I can do all the permutations. Checking that each permutation forms a homomorphism looks very complicated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It looks like it would be a lot of work

Comment: Andreas' answer below allows you to calculate the degrees of the extensions in the lattice. Once you've done that it is left to apply the fundamental theorem of Galois theory to prove $G$ is as claimed. I mean with the alternating groups instead of the full symmetric groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$Note that if $a \in \Q$, then the roots of $x^{3} - a$ are $\alpha, \alpha \omega, \alpha \omega^{2}$, where $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{a} \in \R$, and $\omega$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity, that is, a root of $x^{2} + x + 1$. Thus
$$
\omega = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2} \in \Q[\sqrt{-3}].
$$
This tells you that the first two factors of $G$ are not $S_{3}$ but only $A_{3}$, that is, cyclic.

---

There is a little extra work to do to show that each $x^{3} -  a$ is irreducible over $\Q[\sqrt{-3}]$, for $a = 2, 3$. Clearly
$$
\Size{\Q[\sqrt[3]{a}] : \Q} = 3.
$$
Now note that $\Q[\sqrt[3]{a}] \subseteq \R$, so that
$$
\Size{(\Q[\sqrt[3]{a}])[\sqrt{-3}] : \Q[\sqrt[3]{a}]} = 2,
$$
which yields
$$
\Size{(\Q[\sqrt[3]{a}])[\sqrt{-3}] : \Q} = \Size{(\Q[\sqrt[3]{a}])[\sqrt{-3}] : \Q[\sqrt[3]{a}]} \cdot \Size{\Q[\sqrt[3]{a}] : \Q} = 6.
$$
But then 
\begin{align}
6 &= \Size{(\Q[\sqrt[3]{a}])[\sqrt{-3}] : \Q} \\&= \Size{(\Q[\sqrt{-3}])[\sqrt[3]{a}] : \Q}\\&= \Size{(\Q[\sqrt{-3}])[\sqrt[3]{a}] : \Q[\sqrt{-3}]} \cdot \Size{\Q[\sqrt{-3}] : \Q} \\&= \Size{(\Q[\sqrt{-3}])[\sqrt[3]{a}] : \Q[\sqrt{-3}]} \cdot 2,
\end{align}
whence
$$
\Size{(\Q[\sqrt{-3}])[\sqrt[3]{a}] : \Q[\sqrt{-3}]} = 3,
$$
which means $x^{3} - a$ is irreducible over $\Q[\sqrt{-3}]$.

Comment: But what is the whole Galois group? I want it to be the product of three groups. The problem is the splitting fields are not linearly disjoint. The third primitive root is in the intersection.

Comment: The Galois group should then be $A_{3} \times A_{3} \times S_{2}$. I have given you all the ingredients.

Comment: Hi @AndreasCaranti, how can i get this $3$ cartesian product if the splitting field of the third factor is not an extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$? I saw a theorem about this result but was required that all the splitting field of the factors being extensions besides that fact the the intersection of them should be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.